# Does destroying a fish with a chainsaw add it to the Fishpedia?

Tags: ridiculous-fishing

In the original 2013 version of Ridiculous Fishing, if you catch and shoot a fish for the first time it gets added to the Fishpedia. If you kill a fish with your chainsaw while your lure is going down instead of shooting it, will that fish still get added to the Fishpedia?